# I am Trying to add date picker in dropdownbutton in flutter but when I press the button the date picker isn't opening

Tags: android, flutter

i am trying to add a date picker function inside a alert dialogue in flutter , the date picker should open when i press the dropdown button but its not opening i've used date picker function inside on changed function do i have to also use drop down menu item
I've also added the screenshot below please have a look
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AlertSnd extends StatefulWidget {
  const AlertSnd({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AlertSndState createState() => _AlertSndState();
}

class _AlertSndState extends State<AlertSnd> {
  DateTime datel;
  String _chosenVal;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Dialog(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      child: contentBox(context),
    );
  }

  contentBox(context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black, offset: Offset(0, 10), blurRadius: 10),
              ]),
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(80.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Center(
                  child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      focusColor: Colors.white,
                      value: _chosenVal,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                      items: <String>[
                        'android',
                        'IOS',
                        'Flutter',
                        'Node',
                        'Java',
                        'Python',
                        'PHP',
                      ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: value,
                          child: Text(value),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      hint: Text(
                        'Choose A Subject',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 16,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _chosenVal = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 50,
                ),
                DropdownButton<DateTime>(
                    hint: Text('Choose A Date'),
                    onChanged: (DateTime value) {
                      showDatePicker(
                              context: context,
                              initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                              firstDate: DateTime(2001),
                              lastDate: DateTime(2099))
                          .then((date) {
                        setState(() {
                          datel = date;
                        });
                      });
                    }),
                TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, AttendenceScr.id);
                    },
                    child: Text('Submit')),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, did you already tried change the onChanged to onTap? Because the onChanged doesn't really make sense because there is no items for the user to select to change the value.

Comment: yes i tried on tap but still datepicker didn't open

Comment: Ok, you may add only one item to activate the onChanged, just like my answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you need to add items to activate the Dropdown onChanged, just like this:

```
DropdownButton<DateTime>(
                    hint: Text('Choose A Date'),
                    items: [
                      'Choose A Date'
                    ].map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<DateTime>(child: Text(e))).toList(),
                    onChanged: (DateTime value) {
                      setState(() {
                        showDatePicker(
                            context: context,
                            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
                            firstDate: DateTime(2001),
                            lastDate: DateTime(2099))
                            .then((date) {
                          setState(() {
                            datel = date;
                          });
                        });
                      });
                    })
```

Comment: thanks it worked but what to do if we want show date when date is selected instead of Choose a date

Comment: Simple, make the Datel variable a String with the initial value "Choose A Date", then call the Datel on the hint, when you attribute the date, convert the date to String and done.